# User signup to Azure AD B2C without email, only phone number

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, password-less

So the title says it all. We want an app that doens't depend on an email at all, only on the phone number of the user. Is this possible ?

Edit: 
I need this to authenticate against Azure Functions, if it matters. Maybe Easy-Auth has this ?

Also, I don't care if the solution is hacky. I know I can make mail verification optional, and I don't mind customizing the sign up form so that I remove the email field and submit a fake address instead of the user.

Comment: Why is this too broad ? It is a question about a specific capability of Azure AD B2C, which is entirely non trivial to find out by yourself. I looked for hours. Like everything else in Azure, this is a complex subject. At any given time there are many features in 'preview' or available unofficially. Also, there isn't much more to explain about why I need this feature. I need phone only sign up because I don't want to ask a user for email. Competing services offer this. The answer won't be broad either. Either it can be done in some specific way, or it can't.

Answer (score 4):

Azure AD B2C does not support this currently.  If you're interested in this feature, you can upvote here and receive updates on when this becomes available:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334314-phone-number-sign-up

Comment: For people who stumble on this in the future, looks like this has been completed in the mean time. Details in the link above.